# How can I programmatically export pdf annotations (such as a formula encircled in a rectangle) as images?

Tags: pdf

I'm wondering if it is possible to export some annotations as images. I already know how to export highlighted text as text, but this doesn't work well with equations. If equations were denoted by an annotation, such as a box encircling them, could I convert them all at once to images using a pdf snapshot tool?

It is easy to do each one individually by hand with the pdf snapshot tool. Do any pdf libraries or programs have any tools that let you make image snapshots programmatically, not of whole pages, but of individual equations that are marked somehow with an annotation?

For the purposes of the question, they don't necessarily have to be free programs.
Thanks.

Comment: The goal here was to take a pdf marked with highlights on key text and red rectangles encircling key formulas and convert it to a text file with wiki markup, which has the text from the highlights and for each red rectangle something like {{wiki:1.png}}, a wiki markup that includes the image 1.png when viewed in the wiki. The end result: pdf markup summary including key images and equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sample uses [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/), it will export the page with only one annotation visible at a time:

```cs
using System.IO;
using Amyuni.PDFCreator;
using System.Collections;
//open a pdf document
FileStream testfile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
IacDocument document = new IacDocument(null);
document.SetLicenseKey("your license", "your code");
document.Open(testfile, "");

document.CurrentPageNumber = 1;
IacAttribute attribute = document.CurrentPage.AttributeByName("Objects");

// listobj is an array list of objects
ArrayList listobj = (System.Collections.ArrayList)attribute.Value;
ArrayList annotations = new ArrayList();
foreach (Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacObject iacObj in listobj)
{
    if ((bool)iacObj.AttributeByName("Annotation").Value)
    {
        annotations.Add(iacObj);
        // Put the annotation out of sight
        iacObj.Coordinates = Rectangle.FromLTRB(
                            -iacObj.Coordinates.Left,
                            -iacObj.Coordinates.Top,
                            -iacObj.Coordinates.Right,
                            -iacObj.Coordinates.Bottom);
    }
    else
        iacObj.Delete(false);
}

ArrayList images = new ArrayList();
int i = 0;
foreach (Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacObject iacObj in annotations)
{
    // Back on sight
    iacObj.Coordinates = Rectangle.FromLTRB(
                        -iacObj.Coordinates.Left,
                        -iacObj.Coordinates.Top,
                        -iacObj.Coordinates.Right,
                        -iacObj.Coordinates.Bottom);
    //Draw the page
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    IntPtr hdc = gr.GetHdc();
    document.DrawCurrentPage(hdc.ToInt32(), true);
    gr.ReleaseHdc();
    images.Add(bmp);
    bmp.Save("c:\\temp\\image" + i + ".pdf");

    iacObj.Delete(false); // object not needed anymore
    i++;
}
```

If needed, you can extract the part of the resulting image that corresponds to the annotation by using the Coordinates property of the annotation object.

If you want to extract all objects from a rectangular area (annotations or otherwise) you can replace the loop that collects annotations with a call to the method [IacDocument.GetObjectsInRectangle](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/GetObjectsInRectangle_Method.htm)

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I can extract page to image and then extract the piece of the image that I need with the coordinates. Anyone know how to something similar in a free pdf library or adobe javascript?

Comment: You could combine several GPL libraries for this. You can export pages to images using imagemagic and you can get the (relative) coordinates of annotations using iText, but please be aware that it is not legal to use GPL libraries for free in closed-source commercial applications.

Comment: Good to know. I'm just thinking personal use, not commercial. If I share the results, I'll look up the proper procedure for giving all the credit where it is due.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a full ruby based solution here, using the ruby gems pdf-reader and rmagick (along with an installation of imagemagick).

```rb
require 'pdf-reader'
require 'RMagick'

pdf_file_name='statmech' #without extension
doc = PDF::Reader.new(File.expand_path(pdf_file_name+".pdf"))
$objects = doc.objects

def convertpagetojpgandcrop(filename,pagenum,croprect,imgname)
   pagename = filename+".pdf[#{pagenum-1}]"
   #higher density used for quality purposes (otherwise fuzzy)
   pageim = Magick::Image.read(pagename){ |opts| opts.density = 216}.first
   #factors of 3 needed because higher density TODO: generalize to pdf density!=72
   #SouthWestGravity puts coordinate origin in bottom left to match pdf coords
   eqim =pageim.crop(Magick::SouthWestGravity,...    
   3*croprect[0],3*croprect[1],3*croprect[2]-3*croprect[0],3*croprect[3]-3*croprect[1])
   eqim.write(imgname)
end

def is_square?(object)
   object[:Type] == :Annot && object[:Subtype] == :Square
end
def is_highlight?(object)
   object[:Type] == :Annot && object[:Subtype] == :Highlight
end

def annots_on_page(page)
   references = (page.attributes[:Annots] || [])
   lookup_all(references).flatten
end

def lookup_all(refs)
   refs = *refs
   refs.map { |ref| lookup(ref) }
end

def lookup(ref)
   object = $objects[ref]
   return object unless object.is_a?(Array)
   lookup_all(object)
end

def highlights_on_page(page)
   all_annots = annots_on_page(page)
   all_annots.select { |a| is_highlight?(a) }
end

def squares_on_page(page)
   all_annots = annots_on_page(page)
   all_annots.select { |a| is_square?(a) }
end
def restricted_annots_on_page(page)
   all_annots = annots_on_page(page)
   all_annots.select { |a| is_square?(a)||is_highlight?(a) }
 end
#This block exports a jpg for each 'square' annotation in pdf
doc.pages.each do |page|
   eqnum=0
   all_squares = squares_on_page(page)
   all_squares.each do |annot|
  eqnum = eqnum+1
  puts "#{annot[:Rect]}"
  convertpagetojpgandcrop(pdf_file_name,page.number,annot[:Rect],...
      pdf_file_name+"page#{page.number}eq#{eqnum}.jpg")
   end
 end    

 #This block gives the text of the highlights and wikilinks to the images 
 #TODO:(needs to go in text file)
doc.pages.each do |page|
  eqnum = 0
  annots = restricted_annots_on_page(page)
  if annots.length>0
   puts "# Page #{page.number}"
  end
  annots.each do |annot|
if is_square?(annot)
   eqnum = eqnum+1
   puts "{{wiki:#{pdf_file_name}page#{page.number}eq#{eqnum}.jpg}}"
else
       puts "#{annot[:Contents]}"
end
  end
end
```

This code expands upon example code for the pdf-reader and rmagick gems found online. Few of the lines are original.

Comment: Hi @braydenware. Could you explain how can I implement this code? I don't know Ruby and I use Linux. I am a mathematician and I would love export the content inside rectangles to a single pdf.